# Как задать межзнаковый интервал всему документу docx?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

Как задать межзнаковый интервал всему документу docx через python?

Comment: В `python-docx` "это не реализовано" https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/issues/403

Comment: это я уже понял. какие-нибудь есть варианты еще?